# How to use collector in giveaway command

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a giveaway command for my server, all from my knowledge without following a tutorial.
I'm running into an issue. I don't know how to use the collector's information to determine if there is enough reactions or not, and to get a winner.

My code:

```
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
        };
        
        const collector = message.createReactionCollector({ filter, time: duration });
        
        collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
            console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
        });
        
        collector.on('end', collected => {
            console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
        });

        setTimeout(() => {
            if (collector <= 1) {
                message.channel.send("Not enough people reacted for me to draw a winner")
            return}
            let winner = (m) => m.reaction.cache.get("").users.cache.filter((u) => !u.bot).random();
            channel.send(`Congratulations ${winner} You just won the **${prize}**!`
            );
          }, duration );
```

Any help please? Thank you!

Comment: Try looking at the Discord.JS guide for reaction collectors: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors

Comment: I tried it and I can't understand what I have to do to get a winner and see if there is enough players or not @Elitezen